# How to set dragable oblect in container on randome places jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i work with draggable object, i will have lot of containers at which i need to setup objects.

But problem is that i can't set is on random place, or which i want, it's working like list

[image]

But i want to set up randomly:

[image]

I create [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwyju812/8/) with code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addBtn").click(function() {
    var $div = $("<div>", {
      "class": "alert alert-info draggable alwaysTop",
      text: "Say-Da-Tay!"
    }).draggable();

    $("#dropbox").prepend($div);
  });

  $(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var dropped = ui.draggable;
      var droppedOn = $(this);
      $(dropped).detach().css({
        top: 0,
        left: 0
      }).appendTo(droppedOn);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.alwaysTop {
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-primary parentPanel">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Dropbox</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body  droppable" id="dropbox">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn - btn-warning col-md-2" id="addBtn">
    Add Item
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-success parentPanel">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Final Destination</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body droppable" id="final_dest">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to set object randomy on the container, i want to drag object at random place in container and it's will stay, now it's set to the list

Comment: where is the question ?! Very unclear what you're aiming to do.

Comment: @ths i want to drag object on container on randomy places, now it's going to the list.

Comment: *"random places"* - can you elaborate on what does that mean ? Still not that clear unfortunately.

Comment: @ths if u will press *Add Item* on *Dropbox* will create objects. then when i drag obj, thes go to the column storage, but i want like grid object to drag and save on randomly place

Answer (score 0):

why not use a solution based on an example from the jQuery library
https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default
https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert
All you have to do is change the height of the initial dropbox to whatever you want.

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
      revert:"invalid"
    });
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
      }
    });
  } );

  let btn = document.querySelector(".add-btn")
  btn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    let div = document.createElement("div")
    div.classList.add("draggable","ui-widget-content")
    div.innerHTML = "Drag me"
    let initialDropbox = document.querySelector("#initial-dropbox")
    initialDropbox.appendChild(div)
    $(div).draggable({
      revert:"invalid"
    });
  })
```

```css
body,p{
      margin:0;
    }
    *{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .draggable {
      width: 100px;
      min-height: 100px;
      padding: 0.5em;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
    }

    .droppable {
      width: 150px;
      min-height: 250px;
      padding: 0.5em;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
    }
    .title{
      background: #dccaca;
      padding: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .container{
      display: flex;
      align-items: baseline;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div id="initial-dropbox" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
  <p class="title">Dropbox</p>
  <div class="draggable ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="add-btn">Add item</button>


 
<div class="droppable ui-widget-header">
  <p class="title">Final destination</p>
</div>
 </div>
```